# Text has large gap between COL, text is not left aligning

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have a row with 2 cols, the first one being an image and the second one text, the text is so far to the right and not left aligned next to the image.

```html
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <main class="flex-shrink-0">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h1 class="mt-3 mt-lg-5">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2">
                <div class="col">
                    <img src="/img/eye-5248678__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Logo" width="400" height="250">
                </div>
                <div class="col mt-2 mt-lg-5">
                    <p class="lead">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
                        Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
                        took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has</p>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </main>
```

[image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7jjt.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have two .cols and on desktop it will be 50% each, so you can do 2 things, the first is to convert that .col to .col-4 and .col-8 like so:

```
<main class="flex-shrink-0">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1 class="mt-3 mt-lg-5">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="/img/eye-5248678__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Logo" width="400" height="250">
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 mt-2 mt-lg-5">
            <p class="lead">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
                Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
                took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or the second option is to make the image 100% width.